# Are Arcane Grimoires destructible?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Can the +1/+2/+3 Arcane Grimoires be destroyed? Are they subject to the same environmental damage as a normal spellbook, such as water/fire or do they have the same qualities as an enduring spellbook by virtue of being a +1/+2/+3 magic item?

Comment: You might need to be more specific on what you mean by 'the same environmental damage' because most things worn or carried are not affected by a lot of things, so in effect even mundane spell books are almost indestructible unless the DM goes to special effort

Comment: I was referring more to environmental effects as opposed to spells, i.e. diving underwater would get your spellbook wet unless it's stored somewhere watertight, etc. Depending on the DM, this may or may not cause the spellbook's pages to be unusable, and hence lose all the spells written in them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## An Arcane Grimoire is a magic item and:

> All the items [listed in the magic item section] use the magic items rules in the Dungeon Master's Guide. <sup>TCoE, pg.117</sup>

Which brings us to page 141 of the DMG:

> #### Magic Item Resilience
>
> Thanks to a combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic item is at least as durable as a nonmagical item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. Artifacts are practically indestructible, requiring extraordinary measures to destroy.

So yes, it can be destroyed and probably in the same manner as a normal spellbook. Typically magic items have resistance to all damage but it would be up to the DM to decide whether the grimoire (which is a *leather-bound book*) has any such magical protection.